# Effective approach to running Romex on existing lines.

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle

If a power outlet has an mix of 12 & 14 gauge wire or 14 gauge wire, would it be as effective, provide up to 14 amps, and safe to run 12 gauge Romex to a new outlet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're always allowed to upsize the wire.

So if you have a 15A circuit with 15A breaker, you are required to use at least 14AWG wire.. But if you want to use some 12AWG that is also ok.

There are some reasonable reasons for doing that.